# React Native nested scrollview strange padding

Tags: react-native

I was trying to achieve a vertical scrollable component made out of cards (here called ElementHistory).
Inside each card there are set of photos I want to show. Therefore I've nested an horizontal scrollview inside a vertical scrollview but some strange padding appears and I can't really figure out why.

[image: Expo mobile preview]

here is my react native JSX code

```
const HistoryScreen = props => {

/* not important stuff before */

return (
    <ScrollView style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, paddingTop: 20}} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ElementHistory style={styles.violationContainer}>
            <ScrollView horizontal 
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true} 
                        style={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black'}} 
                        contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png' }} />
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png' }} />
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png' }} />
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png' }} />
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png' }} />
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png' }} />
            </ScrollView>
            <View>
                <ElementText style={styles.titleText}>Anonimity:</ElementText>
                <ElementText style={styles.text}>No anonimity</ElementText>

                <ElementText style={styles.titleText}>Veichle:</ElementText>
                <ElementText style={styles.text}>CAR</ElementText>

                <ElementText style={styles.titleText}>Issue:</ElementText>
                <ElementText style={styles.text}>BAD PARKING</ElementText>

                <ElementText style={styles.titleText}>Position:</ElementText>
                <ElementText style={styles.text}>Via vittoria colonna 54, 20148, Milano, Italy</ElementText>

                <ElementText style={styles.titleText}>Date:</ElementText>
                <ElementText style={styles.text}>10/05/2020</ElementText>
            </View>
        </ElementHistory>
        <View style={{height: 40}}></View>
    </ScrollView>
)
```

And here is my styling (not affecting the padding whatsoever, already tested)

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    violationContainer: {
        margin: 8,
        backgroundColor: Colors.secondary
    },
    image: {
        width: 70,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        marginRight: 15
    },
    titleText: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginTop: 5
    },
    text: {
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});
```

If I set flexGrow property to 0 inside the vertical topmost scrollview I get what I wanted but as soon as I insert another "ElementHistory" item inside the vertical topmost scrollview the problem is still there and the padding seems to increase each time according to the number of elements contained inside the first scrollview which is very strange.

[image: flexGrow0] [image: Elements nested inside vertical scrollview]

```
            […]
                <ElementText style={styles.text}>10/05/2020</ElementText>
            </View>
            </ElementHistory>
            <Text></Text>
            <Text></Text>
            <Text></Text>
            <Text></Text>
            <Text></Text>
            <View style={{height: 40}}></View>
```

EDIT:
I've solved by using a FlatList instead of vertical scrollview but still I'm not sure if that's a bug that should be pointed out to react developers or not